# angular directive , how is directive magically rendered when I do not see a call to it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in a Directives.js file I see the following code

```
app.directive('arpLink', function ($http) {
  return {
scope: {
  link: '=',
  className: '@cl'
},
replace: true,
template:
  '<span ng-click="clicked()">' +
    '<a class="{{ className }}" target="_blank" ng-href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>' +
  '</span>',
link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
  scope.clicked = function () {
    if (this.link !== undefined && this.link.id !== undefined) {
      $http.put('api/links/' + this.link.id, { hitcount: true });
    }
  };
}
```

};
});

This ends up displaying a link button on the home page in which I want to remove this button link , normally I would simply delete a line or two of code in other web applications.

I see that in chrome that code does render out to

```
<span ng-click="clicked()" cl="btn-blue btn-large" arp-link=""  link="link" class="ng-isolate-scope"><a data-blah="adf" class="btn-blue  btn-large" target="_blank" ng-href="http://eso/docold/" href="http://eso /docold/">Old DOC Home Page</a></span>
<a class="btn-blue btn-large" target="_blank" ng-href="http://eso/docold/" href="http://eso/docold/">Old DOC Home Page</a>
```

1. I don't see any files when searching that even call the directive "arpLink"
2. How is this directive called and how can I stop it from being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called using the attribute shown in the markup `arp-link`

The name of the directive is a camelCase version of that attribute.

Directives can be implemented using class, attriute, element and even an html comment

```
<div class="arp-link"></div>
<arp-link></arp-link>
<div arp-link></div>
<!-- arp-link -->
```

The `restrict` option can be used to define which method would reference specific directive you register

To stop it , don't include the directive declaration and/or remove the attribute. Removing only one of them will have no adverse impact...the directive will just never be invoked

Comment: I see that when I comment out the entire directive that a whole bunch of other links are using the arp-link ,  so I'm thinking this might be partially coming from the database  -  so I wish to only hide or not display the link button for the Old DOC Home Page,   ng-href="http://eso/docold/" href="http://eso/docold/">Old DOC Home Page</a>      how can I do that?

Comment: just find the html in whatever template is used on that route that has the attribute and remove the attribute (or the element)

Comment: Oh, that seems like a horrible idea to have  arpLink directive in which nothing is referencing it,... and yes you are correct I can find pages with arp-Link    this seems like a bad design doesn't it?

Comment: that's how angular works. It's not difficult when you are used to it. It's an html declaritive framework

Comment: Ok - noobie here..    so ok  i commented out <div class="col-1-1">
      <span cl="btn-blue btn-large" srp-link link="link"></span>
    </div>    in the home.html  template and that seems to do the trick ,  thx!